# Line side tap for PV install

Tags: wiring

I want to tap directly above the main breaker. Can I just strip the insulation off the conductors and slide a 2/0 Polaris lug over the uncut conductor?

Comment: Context? At a bare minimum you're going to want those feeders to be deenergized. But given what I'm imagining this sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If the power is not off, one little oops means fried person.  Panels usually do not leave enough room to not make oops and the wires you want to work on have no protection that will stop them from frying you.  Most power companies do have free once a year disconnect service.

Answer (score 4):

NO!  Right off the bat, those conductors are always energized, so you're looking at about a 2 megawatt dead short if something gets out of hand.  Neither you nor your house is likely to survive that event.

Now, they do make listed (approved) line side taps which can be applied with less risk.

The second issue is the only reason to line-side tap is grid-tied solar, and that needs the approval of the power company.  Power company won't approve it without permits and inspections, requiring listed items used as designed, and workmanlike work, and many barriers thrown in the way of DIY. Pro installation is also a condition of financing, rebates and tax credits.  Generally this "entitlement" side of a solar setup is a huge chore that exceeds the patience of DIYers.  I mean I'm all for it if you can pull it off; the actual hardware is so cheap the tax credits arguably aren't worth it.

The third issue is "winding your meter backwards" does not work without a contract.  The meters are too smart for that (or too dumb - some will bill you for the power you supply!)